# Python2.6 Backtrack/Ubuntu wxPython

Tags: python, ubuntu, wxpython

I wrote a python app and it needs python2.6. I'm trying to get it to run in Backtrack 4 which is a pen-testing linux distro based on debian/ubuntu. I'v managed to install python2.6 along side of python2.5. Now I'm trying to install wxPython for 2.6 from the repos but I can't get it to install it for python2.6 rather than 2.5. Is there some way i can set a flag to specify what python installation to target? Or do I just need to install it from source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is pre-built version of python, wxwidgets, wxpython in ubuntu packages.

You don't need to build from the sources(unless you have special reasons), you can install it from the following links.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/jaunty/python2.6

http://packages.ubuntu.com/jaunty/libwxgtk2.8-0

http://packages.ubuntu.com/jaunty/python-wxgtk2.8

And also wxPython 2.8 is recommended, you still can find 2.6 though.

Comment: But if I install the python2.6 package, it will remove python2.5 which I still need.